# How to get notification of user tap in a different class?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

I have a class that creates a calendar.  One of the methods finds the date the user tapped, and stores it in a CFGregorianDate object *in that same class*.

I have a need to know *in another class* when the user tapped the calendar date, but after the CFGregorianDate object has been updated, so I can do some backend processing.

How do I get notification of the tap in the second class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider [NSNotificationCenterClass](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) an option for you..

```
 // add this in your anotherClass
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(objectUpdated:) name:@"objectUpdated" object:nil];



 //then post notification after you updated the CFGregorianDate
 NSNotificationCenter *ncSubject = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];  
 [ncSubject postNotificationName:@"objectUpdated" object:nil];  
 [ncSubject removeObserver:self];
```